# How to upload a 9GB file with extension sql.gz to SQL BigQuery Sandbox

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sandbox

I want to upload a 9.6 GB file with the extension .sql.gz to my SQL BigQuery Sandbox (free) account.  I received a message that the file is too big and that I need to upload it from the cloud. When trying to upload it from the cloud, I am asked to create a bucket, and if I want to create a bucket, I get the message:  "billing must be enabled".  Is there any alternative,  specifically for an sql.gz file?

Comment: Identical to your https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73839398/how-to-upload-a-9-6gb-sql-gz-file-to-sql which was rightly closed as off topic. Please stick to the subject which is _programming_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, there is no alternative but to upload `.gz` files files to a bucket in Cloud Storage and use the [bq command-line](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool#creatingtablefromfile) tool to create a new table.

You may [enable billing for your existing project](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project#enable_billing_for_a_project) to use Cloud Storage.

Comment: Thanks, can I also use the trial period of 90 days / $300 credit for this project - for a 9,6 GB dataset?

Comment: Yes you may use the free trial period for [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/free-cloud-features#storage). Just to manage your expectation though, free tier is available in us-east1, us-west1, and us-central1 regions. You may also check this SO post: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=Choose%20one%20answer%20that%20you,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.)

Comment: One more question - with the bq-command-line-tool, can I upload the 9.6GB file, or does it only give me 5 GB storage?  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RdDyF3jVbbE

Comment: The reason why I ask, is as for bq-command, I need to use Cloud Shell.